# Some properties of the global instance are not copied by spread operator or by Object.assign in node v12

Tags: node.js

With node version 8 and version 10, this code works fine:

```
const cpGlobal = {...global};
assert(typeof cpGlobal.Buffer === "function")
```

The same code with node v12.13.1 doesn't work. `cpGlobal.Buffer` is `undefined`, it is not copied from the original `global`. I have tried also `Object.assign` with the same result.

The same happen for other properties, like `process`. Some properties are copied correctly, like `setImmediate`, `setInterval`, ...

Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
const object = global;

const newObject =  {...object}; //this doesn't work for some reason correctly on 12 or above. I am not sure why.

const newObject = Object.assign(object); // this does work for version 12 or above

console.log(typeof newObject.Buffer); // returns undefined with version 12 or above. Version 11 works fine
console.log(typeof object.Buffer); // returns function
```

Node version I tried: v10.17.0, v11.15.0, v12.13.1, v13.2.0.

The `newObject = {...object}` is the problem with version 12 or above. This worked when I changed this to `newObject = Object.asssign(object);`

Could you try this.

Comment: Can you try with the exact code that I have posted? I found the problem only with the global instance.

Comment: What do you mean with global instace. What module provides this?

Comment: 'global' is a variable provided directly by node.js. you don't need to import anything. It is where built-in functions and types are declared. You usually don't need to use directly it, but I'm working on a low level module that has this need.

Comment: Ok, i will try this out tonight. Sorry but I cannot right now 

Comment: I updated the answer. Could you try again with Object.assign() because this does work for me on v12 or above.